# property not found exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-7, classnotfoundexception

I have added category.java and CategoryFacade.java class to query the category table of my affablebean database. The category table contains two columns, i.e "id_cat" and "name". if i use `<a href="category?${category.name}">`in my index.jsp page it works well but in place of "name" when i use id_cat `<a href="category?${category.id_cat}">`  Its shows the error shown below. Could anyone please help me out with this problem. Below you can find all the related page code for your review.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'entity.Category' does not have the property 'id_cat'.

root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'entity.Category' does not have the property 'id_cat'.

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

Here is my Category.java code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author sabin
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findByIdCat", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.idCat = :idCat"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.name = :name")})
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_cat")
    private Short idCat;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "categoryId")
    private Collection<Product> productCollection;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(Short idCat) {
        this.idCat = idCat;
    }

    public Category(Short idCat, String name) {
        this.idCat = idCat;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Short getIdCat() {
        return idCat;
    }

    public void setIdCat(Short idCat) {
        this.idCat = idCat;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Product> getProductCollection() {
        return productCollection;
    }

    public void setProductCollection(Collection<Product> productCollection) {
        this.productCollection = productCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idCat != null ? idCat.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        Category other = (Category) object;
        if ((this.idCat == null && other.idCat != null) || (this.idCat != null && !this.idCat.equals(other.idCat))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Category[ idCat=" + idCat + " ]";
    }

}
```

and here is my CategoryFacade.java code

```
<code>
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package session;

import entity.Category;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author sabin
 */
@Stateless
public class CategoryFacade extends AbstractFacade<Category> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AffableBeanPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public CategoryFacade() {
        super(Category.class);
    }

}
```

and here is my index.jsp page.

```
<div id="indexLeftColumn">
                <div id="welcomeText">
                    <p>[ welcome text ]</p>
                    categoryImagePath:${initParam.categoryImagePath}
                    productImagePath:${initParam.productImagePath}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="indexRightColumn">
                <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}"> 
                     <div class="categoryBox">
                    <a href="category?${category.id_cat}">
                        <span class="categoryLabelText">${category.name}</span>
                        <img src="${initParam.categoryImagePath}${category.name}.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
                </c:forEach>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for solution and experimenting a lot with my code i finally found the solution.
As you can see in my index.jsp code i have written category.id_cat.

```
<a href="category?${category.id_cat}">
```

One should be very careful while using netbeans wizard to create entiy class. My column name in table "category" is id_cat which changes to idCat in Category.java class. Though i thought its accepts the same name id_cat as mentioned in the Category.java class using annotation

```
 @Column(name="id_cat")
```

but i didnot see the variable declare just below,i.e.

```
private Short idCat
```

now to fetch the value i have to access idCat not id_cat. I replaced the code `<a href="category?${category.id_cat}">` with `<a href="category?${category}">` to see what column and values is being set in category variable from ${categories} result. I then found its using idCat=1 and then i went back to my code and found the variable in which the id_cat value from table was initialized. It was using idCat variable as i have mentioned above. I replaced id_cat with idCat and now its working perfectly.